# Google Drive Picker on the website

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-picker

I would like to integrate Google Drive Picker on the website. I created the project on the Google Developer Console and all neccesery ids and keys, my question is how can I secure those credentials in the javascript code? I thought that client id and api key should be always secured or I should here don't worry about that?

Comment: ketch 22 there. but it wont matter it will be secure because its a web client you will have to supply a redirect ui meaning that it will only work from your website.

Comment: If you are wondering why they are supposed to be kept private this might interest you.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585412/can-i-really-not-ship-open-source-with-client-id/28109307#28109307