# How to fetch google analytic data using UA-1111 (property id) without any authentication using php

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to implement Google analytic functionality same as wordpress plugin provide https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/.

Is it possible to fetch google analytic data for any website by just using google analytics UA-11111-1 ID using core php without any authentication( like without passing client_id, client_secret etc..)?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: But why you have tag minus for the question? you are not suppose to do this if you have answer then give it otherwise do you work.

Comment: First, that wasn't me, I just commented. Second, the question is not good as per the Stackoverflow guidelines so people are not happy with it (understandably)

Comment: I need that type of result so have asked and why would I care for people who don't like the questions. this is open community you can ask anything.

Comment: Naresh, no, you can't. Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: do you think that any part in question is not good?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83936/discussion-between-naresh-ramoliya-and-methode).

Answer (score 0):

To access data from the Google Analytics api we use the [Core reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) if you check the page you will notice it says.

> All Requests to the Core Reporting API must be authorized, preferably
>   through OAuth 2.0.

Google Analytics Data is private data owned by the person is admin of the account. The person with admin access can give access to other people by adding there emails to the account.

In order to access Google Analytics data you need to be Authenticated.  If you have access then you can use the API to access the data.  You cant just take someone's analytics tracking code and grab data for there website.  That would be like my being able to grab your Google drive documents or your private Google Photos.

**Question:** Is it possible Google analytic data for any website by just using Google analytics UA-11111-1 ID using core php without any authentication.

*No.  you must be authenticated.*

But, If you have access to the analytics account in question you can use a service account which will not prompt for a user permission.   I am really hoping this is what you meant to ask and not that you are trying to access random peoples Analytics data.

In the case of a wordpress plugin if you are releasing this for others then you should consider a service account.  Your users will have to create there own service account in Google developer console, you [cant release your client_id in a wordpress project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585412/can-i-really-not-ship-open-source-with-client-id/28109307#28109307).   They can then add the service account to there Google Analytics account and will have access to there data on there wordpress site.