# Can I create a new ID Client Oauth without access to console?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-console-developer

I want to create a new Id Client Oauth 2.0 for Google Drive API, then generate the object JSON (oauth credentials), download it and place it in a specific folder, without the use of the console developers google. Is there a script (in php or javascript) that produce this with the email and password of a google account?

I want to create this "standalone script" because I dont want that the client must go before on the google console (although it will be for one-time).

thanks,
Matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to programmatically create a project on [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com).   The only way to create a new project is to do it though the website manually.

You are not going to find a script or anything to allow you to do this.  The only think that remotely resembles this is the [Google Cloud Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/) but its not going to let you create credentials.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @DalmTo !
I'm making an application to save files in a database or google drive, and the customer can't go on the console to create the project, download the json object etc., it is too complicated for him.
so I was wondering if it was possible to automate everything, but I guess the best solution is that I must create the project, download the json object and place it in the project folder for every customer, it is correct?

thanks again

Comment: You may not give a customer your client id and secret.  If your application isn't one that can be run by multiple customers and something that you can store away from the users eyes. They will have to make their own.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/28109307/1841839  That states you cant release the source code of a PHP script to other uses that contains your client ID and client secret.   They will have to make there own manually.