# Google drive python Script for Users-Credentials

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-console-developer

I uploaded few files on `Google-drive` using my gmail account. Now my customers have to go to the drive and download those files. Files on the drive have read and write access and customers can download those files without gmail account.

I studied how i can automate this downloading process using `Python`. I found one wrapper [PyDrive](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/) for `Google-Drive` Rest-api. For this `API` to work, i need to get credentials from the [Google-Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=astute-lyceum-167105).

I want to send that python script to user so that they can download the files but

1. Is it necessary to send the credientials also?
2. Users can't download the files without gmail account?
3. I can't just write a script and send to customers and they just run it without any credentials and gmail-account?

Comment: For the first one: if you are using credentials, yes you need to send it also, but you can guide client to create the own credentials since your file was shared with their gmail.

For the second: you can use API key credentials and send in the code so you could avoid using gmail, but setting up was some what hard (I'm new, and I just achieved with using credentials file, not API key)

For the third: yes, use the API key, include in it, another options is host a server with scripts that create a class to generate API key, and connect to that server to get the key.

Comment: You may **NOT** share your credentials to anyone else it is against the TOS you signed with Google when you created the project.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585412/can-i-really-not-ship-open-source-with-client-id/28109307#28109307  Your customers will need to make there own projects on Google developer console and use their own credentials.