# Reminder, Potentially compromised credentials for Google Cloud Platform/API project | getting this error

Tags: c#, github, google-api, visual-studio-2022

So I'm making an app using data from a google sheets by using the API. I uploaded it to GitHub and I got an email that said this. How am I meant to upload it so the users can have the working app?

Right now its been uploaded in a .JSON file

Comment: Did I get you right:: you included your Google credentials in the code on a public Github repo?

Comment: Yes but I deleted and replaced it and everything

Comment: Unless you deleted the repo it's still in the git history.

Comment: Regenerate the client secrete in your project on google cloud console it will ensure the one you mistakenly uploaded will become invalid.   Instruct your users how to create their own.

Comment: ive already gotten rid of the old private key and am using a new unleaked one, i need to find out how to make it not show up but usable by people who use the project on github

Comment: If you read my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28109307/1841839) you will  understand why you **CANT** its against googles TOS to share your client id and secrete in an open source project.  Teach your users how create their own.   I have serval YouTube videos which explain how to create a client id.